# OneToOne помогите с файлом для liquibase в случае двухстронней связи

Tags: java, liquibase

Изучаю тему связывания таблиц.
Пока разбираюсь с OneToOne.
Таблицу Person сократил ради экономии места. Понятно, что одно имя не сможет однозначно указать на конкретного человека.

Первый вариант - односторонняя связь
У человека есть ИНН и он может быть у него только один. И каждому ИНН прявязан конкретный человек и он тоже может быть только один, но нам не надо хранить в базе инн сведения о его владельце.

Person.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons", schema = "date")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name; 

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inn_id", unique = true)
    private InnBase innBase;
}
```

InnBase.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "inn_base", schema = "date")
public class InnBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "inn_number")
    private int innNumber;
}
```

файл для liquibase

```
<changeSet id="create_person" author="alex">
    <createTable tableName="person" schemaName="date">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>       
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="id_inn" type="INT">
            <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_inn" referencedTableSchemaName="date"
                         referencedTableName="types" referencedColumnNames="id"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="create_inn" author="alex">
    <createTable tableName="inn_base" schemaName="date">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="inn_number" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Второй вариант - двустороняя связь.

У человека есть ИНН и он может быть у него только один. К каждому ИНН привязан конкретный человек и он тоже может быть только один. Но нам необходимо, что бы можно было найти по ИНН его владельца.
В этом случае необходимо изменить класс InnBase.

Person.java:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name; 

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inn_id", unique = true)
    private InnBase innBase;
}
```

InnBase.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class InnBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "inn_number")
    private int innNumber;
    
    @OneToOne (optional=false, mappedBy="innBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    private Person owner;
}
```

На сколько правильно я понял эту тему?

И подскажите как мне во втором случае надо изменить файл liquibase для таблицы inn_base.

Я так понимаю, что во втором случае надо создать третью таблицу для связи:

```
id | person_id | inn_id
```

Но как тогда измениться код сущностей?

Создал таблицы через hibernate. И получилось, что для второго варианта структура таблиц совсем не поменялась.

Comment: можете начать с прочтения [википедийной статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: с этой информацией я знаком. Мне не понятно каким образом добавление (изменение ) аннотаций влияет на структуру таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае все правильно, но излишне будет делать отдельный FK,тоесть

```
@JoinColumn(name = "inn_id", unique = true)
```

в Person entity, потому как у нас не может быть другого InnBase для Preson, мы можем связывать их через id Person, то есть

> FK_PERSON_ON_INNBASE FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES
> InnBase  (id);

вместо

> FK_PERSON_ON_INNBASE FOREIGN KEY (inn_id) REFERENCES
> InnBase  (id);

еще если ddl будет формировать фреймворк, что бы он сделал правильное связывание FK через Person id вместо

> @JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true)

нужно будет использовать аннотацию

> @MapsId в Person например

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons", schema = "date")
public class Person {

@Id
private long id;

@Column
private String name; 

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId
private InnBase innBase;
```

}

> @GeneratedValue
> при этом уже не нужен потому как столбец id будет заполнятся идентификатором InnBasse id

если же ddl будете формиваться не фреймворком, а через другие инструменты, например:
liquiBase,flyWay,или же вы захотите связывать FK написав запрос вручную, достаточно будет

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", unique = true)
private InnBase innBase;
```

Во втором же случаи у вас двунаправленая  связь, и тут очень важно понимать кто является родительской стороной, а кто дочерней, в вашем случаи, родителем будет InnBase, соответственно Person, в таком случае принято написать метод синхронизации
на стороне родителя, например:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class InnBase {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name = "inn_number")
private int innNumber;

@OneToOne (optional=false, mappedBy="innBase", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private Person owner;

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
    if (person == null) {
        if (this.person != null) {
            this.person.innBase(null);
        }
    }
    else {
        person.innBase(this);
    }
    this.person = person;
}


}
```

и это еще не все, есть еще нюансы зависящие с помощью каких инструментов  вы будете делать выборку, и вставку и нюансы связанные с ленивой загрузкой стороны родителя, и по поводу доп. таблицы для связей OneToOne она не нужна,если вы пользуетесь liquiBase для создания ddl для второго варианта, не будет отличатся от первого, главное что бы связывание было в changeSet для таблицы на дочерней стороне, потому как FK будет на дочерней стороне